# How to set the shape rendering attribute to crispEdges using Apache Batik SVG 1.8

Tags: java, svg, batik

I'm trying to get Apache Batik 1.8 to output

```
shape-rendering="crispEdges"
```

instead of the default

```
shape-rendering="auto"
```

in the root `<svg />` node.

I've spotted [`SVGConstants.SVG_SHAPE_RENDERING_ATTRIBUTE`](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/util/SVGConstants.html#SVG_SHAPE_RENDERING_ATTRIBUTE) and [`SVGConstants#SVG_CRISP_EDGES_VALUE`](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/util/SVGConstants.html#SVG_CRISP_EDGES_VALUE), but I'm unsure how to set these attributes to a `SVGGraphics2D` instance.

I've attempted something like suing a SVGGraphics2D(named `SVGGraphics2D`):

```
//svgGraphics.setRenderingHint(SVGRenderingHints.SVG_SHAPE_RENDERING_ATTRIBUTE,
//                             SVGRenderingHints.SVG_CRISP_EDGES_VALUE);
```

However it's [`java.awt.RenderingHints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html) SVGGraphics2D.setRenderingHints expects.

I've also tried:

```
svgGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    svgGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    svgGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
    svgGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
```

however none of the above change the `render-style` attribute to 'crispEdges' in the output SVG file.

(I'm looking into `Document` at the moment, hopefully I can manually change the attribute via XML/strings. I've also spotted [a few related classes in the source code](https://github.com/apache/xmlgraphics-batik/search?l=Java&q=SVG_SHAPE_RENDERING_ATTRIBUTE), but I can't seem to spot a good example/test)

What's the most elegant way to change `render-style` to `crispEdges` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working through the `Graphics2D` interface. Per [Batik code](https://github.com/apache/xmlgraphics-batik/blob/f79ce602fa6244d2a7ff45b57b6a0347e883bc37/batik-svggen/src/main/java/org/apache/batik/svggen/SVGRenderingHints.java#L131), the following `Graphics2D` code adds `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` to SVG:

```
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
```

Comment: Ha! I've tried `svgGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);` but did not expect `RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF)` to set "crispEdges" :))) Thank you!

Comment: I know! Weird! I had to dig into the code to find it. The code search results you posted gave me a thread to pull on, and then I got lucky and ran across the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I found for now is this:

```
Element tlg =  svgGraphics.getTopLevelGroup();
tlg.setAttribute("shape-rendering","crispEdges");
svgGraphics.setTopLevelGroup(tlg);
```

The graphics render crisp now, though, as the code suggests, the attribute is applied as a style to the top level `<g/>` element.

I look forward to seeing cleaner implementations.